# Wolfram Loop Runs Only Once

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolfram-language

Hi I am trying a soft version of Analogue to Digital Converter (ADC) on Wolfram Cloud. The code is given below.

```
min =0.0;
max =15.0;
val=5.0;
avg =0.0;

ans= ConstantArray[0.0,8];
i=0;
while[i<8,i=i+1;
avg = (max+min)/2;

min = If[avg<val , min , avg];
max = If[avg<val, avg, max];

Insert[ans, If[val<avg,0,1], i];

Print[avg]
];

Print[ans];
```

The problem I am facing is that the while loop only runs once and the output is shown below. I have also tried a For loop but results are the same.

```
7.5`
{0.`,0.`,0.`,0.`,0.`,0.`,0.`,0.`}
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: you need to do `ans=Insert[ans,..]`

Comment: Nah no need it works the way I have written

Comment: It will run but that line doesn't do anything. (unless cloud behaves differently from mathematica?)

Comment: may be but works fine if after I capitalized W in while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use capital 'w' for `While`.

```
While[i < 8, i = i + 1;
 avg = (max + min)/2;
 min = If[avg < val, min, avg];
 max = If[avg < val, avg, max];
 Insert[ans, If[val < avg, 0, 1], i];
 Print[avg]]
```

Comment: I can't believe that was the issue...
Thanks